# How To Make MSSQL Ignore The " ' " Inside The Value User Is Giving?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am doing an insert operation from C# and everything goes well except that one insert statement where the user writes something like "roomie's books" in a value because of the ' operator. How can i make Sql ignore the ' inside values?

Answer (score 2):

They're called parameterized queries.

You probably have something like this:

```
 string sql = "SELECT * FROM Bookstores WHERE StoreName = '" + txtStoreName.Text + "'";
```

That is **very bad!** Imagine if the user had typed in something like `';DROP TABLE Bookstores; --` instead of `roomie's books`.

What you need to do is this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Bookstores WHERE StoreName = @StoreName";
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StoreName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtStoreName.Text;

}
```

That assumes you're using raw ADO.Net objects. If you have an ORM like EntityFramework or Dapper the mechanisms for using parameters will look a little different.

The important thing is, the `txtStoreName.Text` value is NEVER directly substituted into the SQL code, not even on the server. It's sent to the server separately from the SQL, so there's no possibility of ever contaminating the SQL with user input. You need to fix **EVERY QUERY** in your application work this way; anything less is practically begging to get hacked, and this is one of those things that's too important to even do wrong for learning or prototypes.

This also tends to perform better, because it allows the server parse the query code once and cache the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Joel gave the right answer, but for completeness' sake, I would would like to add that you can escape the ' character in a string literal in T-SQL by adding another one.

So, for instance

```
INSERT INTO BookStores ([Name]) VALUES ('Roomie''s Books')
```

But like Joel said, you should *never* do this, especially for user-entered data, and use parameters when passing data to SQL Server from code instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, unfortunately boss wants me to use it this way otherwise I would definitely add with parameters. And I cannot add another ' to the value to fix the issue since I don' t know what the user is giving.

Comment: Does your boss explicitly prohibit parameters? I honestly find that hard to believe, and even so, you should probably try talking to him about that.

Comment: You could use the string.Replace function to replace all the single apostrophes with doubles.